# IntegrityError: may not be NULL

Tags: python, django

I'm pulling my hair out with this. When I attempt to add a 'Product' from my admin page, I'm getting an IntegrityError: main_product.img may not be NULL.

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    short = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductImages(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

class ProductFeatures(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    feature = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Admin.py

```
class ProductFeaturesAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductFeatures
    extra = 1

class ProductImageAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductImages
    extra = 1

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'price', 'in_stock')
    inlines = [ProductFeaturesAdmin, ProductImageAdmin]
admin.site.register(Product,ProductAdmin)
```

I was using Pillow to resize images when being upload, so I had a custom save() function in my ProductImages model. I removed that thinking it was the problem, but it's still not working. As you can tell, I'm really new to Django and Python. Any and all help appreciated.

**Edit**: forgot to mention that I've added blank=true and null=true to Product.img, then used South to migrate the table.

**Edit 2:** This is my new ProductImages model.

```
class ProductImages(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

I used South and ran:

```
python manage.py schemamigration main --auto
python manage.py migrate main
```

Still having the error. If I were to add the img field to my Products model, how would I be able to add multiple imgs in the admin panel?

Comment: I don't see `img` in `Product` model.

Comment: With ProductImages linked to Product, wouldn't the ProductImages.img become Product.img?

Comment: img should be direct attribute in Product, otherwise it would be something like main_productimages.img. Wild guess is that you originally had img in Product model later on changed it to separate model but didn't do database migrations.

Comment: i do not see img field having null = True. If null is not set to true, then the field has to have value if you want to successfully save an object. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you need to add `null=True` in the img field, So make it `img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)`.
The difference is that because `blank=True` decides that whether the fields will be required by the forms. `blank=False` means that field cannot be blank and `blank=True` means field will not be required. 
Regarding `null=True` sets NULL in column of your DB which will solve your issue.

Comment: Adding blank=True is enough - Underlying implementation of ImageField is CharField and it's adviced not to use null=True for CharFields.

Comment: I have tried removing blank=True and adding null=True. I've tried adding both. I migrate the DB and I still can't get it to work. I'd really like to get this to work without having to delete my database and start over from scratch.

Comment: Can you access DB with phpmyadmin? you need to remove `not null` constraint from DB manually if possible. see if that works

Comment: For whatever reason, that was the issue. Thank you so much! Just ran the schema to remove the img field from the Product table, and now it works perfect!